# Sort Email:Pass List by first occurrence of each email

Tags: regex, sorting

I want to sort a email:password by first occurrence of each email.

Example list:

```
email@example.com:passsword1
email@example.com:passsword2
email@example.com:passsword3
email1@example.com:passsword1
email1@example.com:passsword2
email1@example.com:passsword2
```

So only

```
email@example.com:passsword1
email1@example.com:passsword1
```

should be kept as result.

With my limited Regex skills I worked out this one but I guess I misunderstand something:

```
^(.*)(\r?\n\1)+(?=:)
```

Comment: Using regex for this is batshit crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```java
^((.*:).*)(?:\r?\n\2.*)+
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/bn9qdX/1), use `g` and `m` flags.

**Explanation**

```java
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*                       any character except \n (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \r?                      '\r' (carriage return) (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \n                       '\n' (newline)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \2                       what was matched by capture \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )+                       end of grouping
```